# How to generate Canvas moving Waves using dynamic x,y values in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

[image]

I have x,y dynamic array values...

Using x,y values generate moving sine ,triangular,square,sawtooth waves in HTML5 canvas....

Comment: What did you try so far and where in your code did you run into problems? (please share). Do you need specific frequency and amplitude or just "waves".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unaltered sine wave is obvious--Math.sin(x), but here are the others...

Given:

```
p = period
o = oscillation
x = x coordinate
```

Find y (the y coordinate):

```
// squared sine
function squareY(x) {
    return( (x%p)<o?o:0 );
}

// sawtooth sine
function sawY(x){
    return( x%p );
}

// triangular sine
function triY(x){
    return( Math.abs((x%p)-o) );
}
```

In sample plots:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var p=30;    // period
var o=15;   // oscillation

// plot sawtooth sine wave

ctx.beginPath();
for(var x=0;x<120;x++){
    var y=sawY(x);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
}
ctx.stroke();


// plot squared sine wave

ctx.beginPath();
for(var x=0;x<60;x++){
    var y=squareY(x);
    y+=75; // just offsetting so drawings don't overlap
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
}
ctx.stroke();


// plot triangular sine wave

ctx.beginPath();
for(var x=0;x<60;x++){
    var y=triY(x);
    y+=150; // just offsetting so drawings don't overlap
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
}
ctx.stroke();
```

**[ Added example animation ]**

```
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth=3;

    var p=30;    // period
    var o=15;   // oscillation

    var fps = 60;
    var n=0;
    animate();
    function animate() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            // Drawing code goes here
            n+=1.5;
            if(n>300){
                n=0;
            }
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            for(var x=0;x<n;x++){
                var y=sawY(x);
                ctx.lineTo(x,y+50);
            }
            ctx.stroke();        

        }, 1000 / fps);
    }


    // sawtooth sine
    function sawY(x){
        return( x%p );
    }
```

Comment: To animate: instead of calculating the plot inside a for-loop, just calculate the plot inside an animation-loop over time.  If you're new to animation loops, check out requestAnimationFrame (or the older-but-still-useful setInterval or setTimeout). Cheers!  :)

Comment: Added example animation code to my answer...http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/DAShs/

Comment: @markE : if i may, you're using both rAF and timeout, so you're shooting twice in the head :-)  http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/DAShs/1/

Comment: @GameAlchemist: setTimeout is used here to throttle RAF to a specified frames-per-second.  Both RAF and setTimeout are async...so no bullets required!  http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/  ;)

Comment: I see, the idea *seems* good, but is definitively not : 1) setTimeout has a too big overhead for a 15ms time. 2) even with setInterval, not being in sync with screen will make 15 then 30 ms randomly in between two frames. 3) this is a perfect fail for 50 Hz or 75 Hz screen. :-0

Comment: @GameAlchemist:  Please Be Nice!  This is just an example, not production code.

Comment: @markE : Oh of course, no offense intended, we're just having fun discussing about this amazing language that is Javascript !

Comment: Many traditional solutions come to mind: 1. Offer a "topped" chart which only shows part of the chart including some max/min Y values. 2.  Offer a "scaled" chart where every y-increment = 100.  3. When the chart exceeds the current canvas height, use context.scale to bring the excessive values back in the canvas.  4. Have Y be a "magnitude" scale where every 100px in increased height shows values 10 times larger than the previous 100px section (like an earthquake magnitude chart).

Comment: ECG waves (in all their variations) aren’t mathematical formulae, they are biological representations.  So you would simulate that biological wave using a series of context.lineTo and context.bezierCurveTo.  The P,T,U intervals would be curves and the Q,R,S spikes and all rests would be lines.    Give it a try!

Comment: This is getting a bit off-topic to your original question!  OK, so plot those y's using something like this: var x=0;
var previousY;
function plotY(y){
  if(previousY){
    context.beginPath(); 
    context.moveTo(x,previousY);  
    x+=10; 
    y/=5000; 
    context.lineTo(x,y); 
    context.stroke(); 
  }
  previousY=y;
}

Comment: **We're way off the original question**...OK, one last time. Here is a Fiddle plotting your y values above.  Since I don't have an ecg machine, I plot the values in a for-loop.  Your values will come in from the machine over time and the plot will move to the right until the end of the canvas.  At that point, you need clear the canvas and reset the x-coordinate to zero. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/XkDxF/

Comment: You are plotting Y values from the machine over time.  The X value would be time.  It's your design decision how you chop up that time.  However you decide to design it, X will get larger over time until the canvas size is reached.  Then the canvas gets cleared and X is reset to zero.

Comment: WADR, I've already given you all the parts to do sample moving waves.  Just use this animation example I've already given you and plug in your ecg data: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/DAShs/  Take a breath...look at the code...look at your data...I know you can do it!   Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This came in our exam. I wrote your answer <3